# Getting Windows Azure Shared Caching to work with ReportViewer

Tags: session, azure, reportviewer, session-state, report-viewer2010

[Azure's shared caching session provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278339.aspx) gives intermittent System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException session errors with [Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SyncList](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appfabricctp/thread/6ffe2f0a-c482-4514-9cf1-14685f0ecd3a/) with the serializing reportviewer with our LOCAL processing of reports.

The only resolve Microsoft appears to have is a [hotfix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh825825.aspx) that has to be installed during each startup of the webrole. Seems like a common control that others would be using. Has anyone else found a better solution that still uses shared caching for managing session?

REPORT VIEWER 2012
Has anyone tried using ReportViewer 2012 in windows azure with azure shared caching? They claimed on [this email from Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appfabricctp/thread/6ffe2f0a-c482-4514-9cf1-14685f0ecd3a/) that this issue of lacking the default parameter-less constructor would be fixed in the version after ReportViewer 2010. Before i went through the process of trying it out wondered if others have had out-of-the-box success with the ReportViewer 2012 when using Azure's shared caching session provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I upgraded to the 2012 version of the report viewer and no longer need the hot fix.  Just as an additional hint, make sure you install the latest version of the report viewer and the version that ships with 2012 doesn't get updated out of band.  To get the latest version you can [download the redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=35747).

Comment: ok that's really good news - wanted to avoid the hotfix if i could. guessing that the hotfix did really fix the issue for you in reportviewer2010 before you moved to reportviewer2012

Comment: Two things I should add.  Before upgrading the control, I upgraded to .net 4.5, which also fixed the problem.  Also the control stores quite a bit in session, so if you run a few reports you will probably exceed the capacity of the cache.  So it's a good idea to clean up session when you navigate away.

Comment: that's helpful info - thanks!
they mentioned the first and apparently better option of using a session-less reportviewer but it seemed to be for remote report (SSRS server) usage (not in-proc localserver) as the authentication properties were not on the localreport object
some have mentioned that reportviewer2012 control runs slower than the reportviewer2010 control - hope they were incorrect - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/26f2baae-339f-4efa-a030-100cac750724/

Comment: i tried using the hotfix and found that it increased deployment times exponentially, and the end result was that using shared session for session is SLOWER than using sql azure for session - so staying with using sql azure for session since it's more reliably faster and does not require these tweaks. thanks for the info.